# add_action template_redirect not working for home page

Tags: functions, actions

I am using bimber theme on latest wordpress. I wanted to force all frontpage views behind a login and added the following code in bimber's functions.php

```
function members_only() {
    // Check to see if user in not logged in and not on the login page
    if( !is_user_logged_in() && (is_home()||is_front_page())){
        auth_redirect();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'members_only' );
```

But this works for individual posts but not for my home page. How do i fix this?

Comment: If you want all the site behind a login, why do you check `is_home()` or `is_front_page()`? Why don't just `if( !is_user_logged_in() ) auth_redirect();`?

Answer (score 2):

Be careful not to confuse the two query conditionals.

Whether [is_home()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/) or [is_front_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/) return true or false depends on the values of certain option values.

When using these query conditionals:

- If 'posts' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ):

  - On the site front page:

    - is_front_page() will return true
    - is_home() will return true
  - If assigned, WordPress ignores the pages assigned to display the site front page or the blog posts index
- If 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ):

  - On the page assigned to display the site front page:

    - is_front_page() will return true
    - is_home() will return false
  - On the page assigned to display the blog posts index:

    - is_front_page() will return false
    - is_home() will return true

**Reference:**
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/#usage

---

To force visitors (not logged in) to log in when viewing your front page, try changing your conditional statement to this:

```
function members_only() {
    // Check if user in not logged in and on the front page
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_front_page() ) {
        auth_redirect();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'members_only' );
```

---

> I wanted to force all frontpage views [...]

If by "all frontpage views" you meant the entire site, and not just your site's "front page," I recommend you install the [Force Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-login/) plugin to easily and simply accomplish this.